# Original variable still changes with .clone or .dup

Tags: ruby

When I execute this program, the original_couples list and the new_couples list are always the same. I thought using .clone or .dup was supposed to be a way of copying without changes being made to the original variable. So why is it happening here?

```
def swingers(couples)

    original_couples = couples

    new_couples = original_couples.clone

    swap_index1 = rand(3)
    swap_index2 = rand(3)

    new_couples[swap_index1][0], new_couples[swap_index2][0] = new_couples[swap_index2]    [0], new_couples[swap_index1][0] 

    puts original_couples
    puts new_couples
end
swingers([
  ["Clyde", "Bonnie"],
  ["Paris", "Helen"],
  ["Romeo", "Juliet"]
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dup` or `clone` in Ruby is a *shallow* clone, meaning that only the outer object is cloned, not its children. In your case, this means that the `couples` array is copied, but not each individual couple.

If you want it to be a *deep* clone, you need to do it manually for the stdlib arrays:

```
new_couples = original_couples.map { |couple| couple.clone }
```

If you are in a domain where copies of collections are often necessary, or you are trying to work in a more functional style, I suggest you take a look at the [`Hamster` gem](https://github.com/hamstergem/hamster), that brings immutable data structures to ruby.